# Add Lines around an Image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Here guys,

I would like to add 4 lines of View in my Android screen. I was able to add 2 Lines, one on the top and one on the left but I don't know how to add one on the right and one on the bottom.

Here is my XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.25"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imvBalle"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.482"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/balle" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/lineTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/lineLeft"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf` and `layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` constraints:

```
    <View
        android:id="@+id/lineRight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/lineBottom"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

Comment: It does not work; it stay at the same position that left and bottom

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You can add background around your view by creating a border shape.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >

            <stroke 
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#000000"
                android:dashWidth="5dp"></stroke>

        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```